# Problems resuming computation in pytorch using checkpoints

Tags: pytorch

it's the first time I use checkpoints and I'm encountering a problem that I can't understand. The reason why I use checkpoints is because I have a time limit in the use of GPUs, so I need my code to work for a while, save checkpoints, and when I have the opportunity to launch it again to resume from where it left.
To sum up my code loads a model, loads imagenet validation dataset, creates a dataloader and starts a loop to pass batches of images to a function that I wrote that does things. Keep in mind that I'm not doing any training, just operations on the images, passing them to the model to test things.

As you can see (in theory) when the code launches again, it should go in the folder where the checkpoints get saved and retrieve the last one that has been created. It is successful in doing so, no problems up until now. So let's see the code and then I'll say what's not working.

```py
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import default_collate

def create_data_loader(dataset, batch_size, device):
    val_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, \
                            collate_fn=lambda x: tuple(x_.to(device) for x_ in default_collate(x)))
    return val_loader

 def main(args):
    # Loading pre-trained model
    model = ...
    config = ...
    T = ...

    # Obtaining ImageNet validation dataset from folder
    val = ImageFolder(
        root='path_to_folder_here',
        transform=T
    )
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)
    val_loader = create_data_loader(val, args.batchsize, device)
    print("Number of batches:", len(val_loader))
    # Initializing progress variables
    start_batch = 0
    
    # Creating variables that I want to save in checkpoints here
    # ...
    
    # Checking if checkpoint directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(args.checkpoint_dir):
        os.makedirs(args.checkpoint_dir)
        print("Created checkpoints directory", args.checkpoint_dir)

    # If the checkpoint directory is not empty
    if os.listdir(args.checkpoint_dir):
        # Getting the name of the latest checkpoint file added to the directory
        files_in_dir = os.listdir(args.checkpoint_dir)
        sorted_files = sorted(files_in_dir, key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(args.checkpoint_dir, x)), reverse=True)
        latest_checkpoint = sorted_files[0]
        print("Found latest checkpoint created:", latest_checkpoint)
        checkpoint = load_checkpoint(os.path.join(args.checkpoint_dir, latest_checkpoint))
        start_batch = checkpoint['batch']
        # Retrieving other variables from checkpoint here


    total_batches = len(val_loader)
    for j, (images, _) in enumerate(val_loader, start=start_batch):
        print(f"Processing batch {j}/{total_batches} - Bacth size: {len(images)}, Number of images: {images.shape[0]}")
        batches_left = total_batches - j
        print(f"{batches_left} remaining")
        result = myFunction(...)
        #Doing things with result here to use after out of the for loop
        #...
        
        print("Batch:" + str(j) + "finished")
        j+=1

        # Checkpoint every 'args.freq' batches
        if j % args.freq == 0:
            save_checkpoint({
                'batch': j,
                # Saving other variables ...
            }, f"{args.checkpoint_dir}/checkpoint_{j}.pth")
```

Well, Imagenet validation dataset has 50000 images, my batchsize is 256, total batches is 196.
My code the first time managed to do 168 batches, when it gets called the second time seems like it starts from there, cause I get printed:

Found latest checkpoint created: checkpoint_168.pth
Checkpoint loaded from checkpoints/checkpoint_168.pth
start
Processing batch 168/196 - Bacth size: 256, Number of images: 256
28 remaining
Batch:168finished
.
.
.

So I let it continue...the problem? It doesn't stop. It's still going, at the moment the last things printed are:

Processing batch 195/196 - Bacth size: 256, Number of images: 256
1 remaining
Batch:195finished
Processing batch 196/196 - Bacth size: 256, Number of images: 256
0 remaining
Batch:196finished
Processing batch 197/196 - Bacth size: 256, Number of images: 256
-1 remaining
Batch:197finished
Processing batch 198/196 - Bacth size: 256, Number of images: 256
-2 remaining

and it goes on if I let it. Can you help me understand what is happening? Shouldn't my code do the first images in the dataloader and when resuming keep going with the remaining images? It's clearly doing more, or maybe redoing things that should have already been done, I don't understand what I'm seeing.

Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you're handling the data loader.

The line `val_loader = create_data_loader(val, args.batchsize, device)` creates a fresh data loader that hasn't generated any batches. If you use it in a for loop, it will generate 196 batches, one at each iteration, starting at batch 0 and ending at batch 195.

Later on, when you do `for j, (images, _) in enumerate(val_loader, start=start_batch):`, this loop will run 196 times no matter what. Here the `start` parameter of `enumerate` does not skip the first `start_batch`es of `val_loader`, it only makes `j` start at `start_batch` instead of `0`, and end at `start_batch + 195` instead of 195. The `val_loader` is still pumping 196 batches, not `196 - start_batch`.

To skip everything before `start_batch` you can do something like:

```py
for j, (images, _) in enumerate(val_loader):
    if j < start_batch:
      continue
    ...
```

The loop will still run 196 times, but it will only process from batch `start_batch` onwards.

Comment: Hey @CarlosGDCJ, thanks for answering! I completely forgot to add the function create_data_loader in my original post, just edited it so you can see. I guess your point still stands tough. Gonna try with your fix as soon as I can and come back to report!